# node.js testing promise results in Error: Promise rejected with no or falsy reason

Tags: node.js, promise, mocha.js, es6-promise

When running Mocha, i get the error:

> Error: Promise rejected with no or falsy reason

on the promise function i'm trying to write tests for.

I have a class like this:

```
class Parser {
  constructor(jobName, jobExchange) {
    this.jobName = jobName;
    this.jobExchange = this.jobExchange;
  }

  parse(job) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject ) => {
      let jobJSON = JSON.parse(job.content);
      return this._isRelevant(jobJSON) ? resolve(jobJSON) : reject();
    });
  }

  _isRelevant(job) {
    return job.exchange_name === this.jobExchange &&
      job.__CLASS__ === this.jobName;
  }
}

module.exports = new Parser(process.env.AMQP_JOB, process.env.AMQP_EXCHANGE);
```

and then a test like:

```
const parser = require('../../job/Parser');

describe('Parser', () => {
  describe('parse', () => {
    it('resolves', async () => {
      let job = {
        content: '{"__CLASS__": "abc","exchange_name": "abc"}'
      }
      const result = await parser.parse(job);
      expect(result).to.equal('promise resolved');
    });
    // it('rejects', async () => {

    // });
  });
});
```

and i run my tests from the command line, like: `env AMQP_JOB=abc AMQP_EXCHANGE=abc mocha`

So what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Think the problem must be related to the env vars not being set correctly and the promise is rejecting. I'd output those vars to the console during the test to verify.

Comment: Just testing it now, but it actualy looks like i've messed up my constructor with `this.jobExchange = this.jobExchange;`

Comment: @Jarede...yep that'll do it! I initially misread your code as I suspected that you were setting the wrong value but then realised that wasn't the case but was still sure the problem had to be around that. Now you've pointed out the constructor... that's definitely the problem :)

Comment: i'm an idiot.  though that error is the least helpful thing ever.

Comment: I'm curious. Why do you make synchronous code async?

Comment: @jarede the error is useful because it definitely marks the state when your test (the calling code) has not got a catch block to handle the 'empty' (simply falsifying it) promise rejection or in your case, this.jobException=this.jobException. There is no such value and hence the promise rejection happened but with 'empty' reasons. 

I have added a sample code/test for it in the answer. Please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
return this._isRelevant(jobJSON) ? resolve(jobJSON) : reject();
```

You are rejecting a promise with no arguments. You should instead reject it with something like `new Error('job not relevant')`.

Normally, when the promise returned to mocha rejects, mocha will display whatever error you provided. In this case, since you didn't provide one, you're seeing that 'unhelpful' message instead.

Like others, though, I really wonder why you're making the parse method asynchronous at all. :\

Answer (score 0):

May be helpful to catch your error.

You can either wrap your promise in a try / catch or use the conventional promise `.then()` / `.catch()`

```
try {
    const result = await parser.parse(job); 
}catch(err) {
    console.log('err', err)
}
```

or

```
await parser.parse(job).then(res => {
    console.log(result)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('err', err)
})
```

Comment: I'm not even sure how the second variation of that works :/

Answer (score 0):

```
// asyncpromiserejection.js 

class asyncpromise{ 
    constructor(s){
        this.s=s
    }
PTest(){    
    var somevar = false;
    somevar=this.s;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (somevar === true)
            resolve();
        else
          // throw new Error("Promise rejcted")
            reject();
    });
}
}
module.exports=asyncpromise

// test.js

const assert=require('chai').assert
const asyncpromise=require('./asyncpromiserejection.js')
describe("asyncTests", () => {
it("handles Promise rejection",async ()=>{
    var t=new asyncpromise(false)
    await t.PTest().then(function () {
     console.log("Promise Resolved");
})
})        
});
```

[image]

Whereas, if you use the `catch`in the test, the promise rejection for an empty promise gets handled, like so:

```
const assert=require('chai').assert
const asyncpromise=require('./asyncpromiserejection.js')
describe("asyncTests", () => {
it("handles Promise rejection",async ()=>{
    var t=new asyncpromise(false)
    await t.PTest().then(function () {
     console.log("Promise Resolved");
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log("Promise rejected")
   // assert.equal(error.message,"Promise rejected")
})
})        
});
```

[image]